# codeigniter Upgrade from 1.5.4 to new version set_fields() Error

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, object

```
    $fields['password']         = "Password";
    $fields['confirm_password'] = "Confirm Password";
    $fields['customer_number']  = "Customer Number";
    $fields['customer_password']  = "Customer Number";
    $fields['first_name']       = "First Name";
    $fields['last_name']        = "Last Name";
    $fields['company_name']     = "Company Name";
    $fields['email_address']    = "Email Address";
    $fields['confirm_email']    = "Confirm Email Address";
    $fields['phone_number']     = "Phone Number";
    $fields['street']           = "Street Address";
    $fields['city']             = "City";
    $fields['zip_code']         = "Zip Code";
    $fields['state']            = "State";
    $fields['country']          = "Country";

    $this->form_validation->set_fields($fields);
```

I get the Error

** Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::set_fields() **

I know this error is because Validation library is depreciated and replaced by the Form_Validation

But is there any replacement in current library  without changing much of the code ?

Comment: I never used the 1.5 branch, but it shouldn't be too hard to change it over to the set_rules() format.  Regular expression find & replace would get you halfway there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any replacement in current library without changing much of the code ?

There is no quick/easy way to migrate this code (your form field config) to the newer version, it must be done manually. If your old config was like:

```
$fields['password'] = "Password";
```

You'll need to change it to:

```
$fields[] = array(
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password'
);
```

And use `set_rules()`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($fields);
```

This is a major upgrade to your Codeigniter installation (Release Date: July 12, 2007... v1.5 is quite old by now) so there's no point in fiddling around trying to half-upgrade your code, just bite the bullet and make sure to test.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment.So I upgraded till 1.7.2 which works with PHP5 which was the only requirement I need to full fill as of now.

Answer (score -1):

Make no sense dude, the best I can come up with.

```
$this->form_validation // automatically assign's {key}{value} pairs via $_POST
```